# Replacing new factor levels with manual values in linear regression

Tags: r

I have such two data frames(df1 and df2):

df1:

```
  dependent factor
     4      a
     4      b
     3      b
     8      c
     3      d
     5      e
     6      e
     2      a
```

df2:

```
  dependent factor
     2      f
     5      d
     3      e
     9      e
     5      g
     2      e
```

Namely:

```
df1<-data.frame(dependent=c(4,4,3,8,3,5,6,2),factor=as.factor(c("a","b","b","c","d","e","e","a")))
df2<-data.frame(dependent=c(2,5,3,9,5,2),factor=as.factor(c("f","d","e","e","g","e")))
```

data in df1 is used to estimate parameter estimates of a linear regression:

```
    reg<-lm(formula=dependent~factor,df1)
```

result is:

```
> coef(reg)
(Intercept)     factorb     factorc     factord     factore 
        3.0         0.5         5.0         0.0         2.5
```

By using these estimates, I want to predict dependent variables of df2. But df2$factor has two new factor levels "f" and "g". So the function:

```
predict(reg,df2)
```

gives such an error:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor factor has new levels f, g
```

For new levels, I want to assign their factor value as "0". How can I do that? Is there a way to do this? My real data is much more complex. I have much more factor variables where each can have new levels in the second data frame. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to omit observations, which introduce new factor levels, like `predict(reg,df2[!df2$factor %in% setdiff(levels(df2$factor), levels(df1$factor)), ]) `?

Comment: No, I dont want to omit new levels. I just want to set their estimates manually as "0" and then predict dependent value. For this example, setting the new levels as 0 will make dependent values as 0. But just imagine there much more idependent variables. What can be done in that situation.

Comment: How does my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the coefficients to 0 for the new levels means that the prediction will be equal to the intercept (see how in `df1` predicted values for levels with slope 0 are equal to the intercept). This means you just need replace these values with the intercept.

I added to @lukeA's code to produce the following predictions for `df2`:

```
pred=predict(reg,df2[!df2$factor %in% setdiff(levels(df2$factor), levels(df1$factor)), ])
ifelse(rownames(df2) %in% attr(pred,"names"), pred, reg$coefficients[1])
  # [1] 3.0 5.5 5.5 5.5 3.0 5.5
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but the answer is not the exact thing what I am looking for. Imagine there is one more factor(factor2) in df1 which is also a factor of the regression application. And same problem can be exist for factor2, factor2 may have new levels in df2.

Comment: Hmm yeah that makes sense. Probably should update your question with an example like this. I'd also caution this statistical approach. With many factors you might run out of degrees of freedom (unless you have a very large N). Also, I can't think of any any situation that it'd make sense to get predictions while forcing parameter estimates to be 0 (but there might be a valid reason to do this).